# adding ticking sound to an analog clock

Tags: qt, qml

How to add ticking sound to an analog clock in Qt or Qml?
The following is my codes for the clock.

```
   Canvas
    {
        id : canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: 740; height: 680  //size of canvas
        onPaint:                // reimplement drawing function
        {
            var ctx = getContext("2d"); //get 2D Context
            drawBack(ctx);
            drawDot(ctx);

            var date = new Date();          //get date
            var hours =  date.getHours()     //get hour
            hours = hours%12;
            var minutes =  date.getMinutes()
            var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
            var timestr =date.toLocaleString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            console.log(date.toLocaleString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
            drawSecond(seconds,ctx);

            drawHour(hours,minutes,ctx);
            drawMinute(minutes,seconds,ctx);
            drawSecond(seconds,ctx);

         }
    }

    function drawBack(ctx)
    {
        var r = 200;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(width/2,height/2);
        ctx.clearRect(-r,-r,r*2,r*2);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.arc(0,0,r-5,0,Math.PI*2,false);  //outer circle
        ctx.stroke();

        var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]; //numbers in clock
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";            //set font
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            var rad = 2*Math.PI/12*numbers[i]-3.14/2;
            var x = Math.cos(rad)*(r-30);
            var y = Math.sin(rad)*(r-30);
            ctx.fillText(numbers[i],x,y);
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 2;   // for scales
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 <60; ++i2)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            var rad2 = 2*Math.PI/60*i;
            var x3 = Math.cos(rad)*(r-15);
            var y3 = Math.sin(rad)*(r-15);
            var x2 = Math.cos(rad)*(r-10);
            var y2 = Math.sin(rad)*(r-10);

        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawHour(hour, minute, ctx)   //draw hours
    {
        var r = 200;
        ctx.save();               // save the state
        ctx.beginPath();          // this line is necessary
        ctx.lineWidth = 7;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";    //set the style
        ctx.translate(width/2,height/2);

        var rad = Math.PI*2/12*hour+Math.PI*2*minute/12/60-Math.PI;
        ctx.rotate(rad);
        ctx.moveTo(0,-10);
        ctx.lineTo(0,r/2-10);
        ctx.stroke();             // fill or stroke is necessary
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function drawMinute(minute,second,ctx)   //draw Minute
    {
        var r = 200;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();     //necessary
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.translate(width/2,height/2);

        var rad = Math.PI*2*minute/60 + Math.PI*2*second/60/60 -Math.PI;
        ctx.rotate(rad);
        ctx.moveTo(0,-10);
        ctx.lineTo(-10,r*3/5-10);
        ctx.stroke();               //like pen in Qt
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function drawSecond(second,ctx)     //draw Second
    {
        var r = 200;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.translate(width/2,height/2);
        ctx.strokeStyle="#ff0000";
        var rad = Math.PI*2*second/60-Math.PI;
        ctx.rotate(rad);
        ctx.moveTo(0,-20);
        ctx.lineTo(0,r*4/5-10);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function drawDot(ctx)
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(width/2,height/2);
        ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
        ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();                     //like a brush
        ctx.restore();
    }
    Timer {
             interval: 1000; running: true; repeat: true
             onTriggered: canvas.requestPaint();    //trigger Timer
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wav file with a ticking sound and [SoundEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-soundeffect.html). You need to import QtMultimedia in your QML file.

```
SoundEffect {
    id: playTick
    source: "tick.wav"
}

Timer {
    interval: 1000; running: true; repeat: true
    onTriggered: { 
        canvas.requestPaint()
        playTick.play()
    }
}
```